# Using SpringFrameWork @Async for methods that return void

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm using the Spring Boot framework as my backend.

This is one of the calls I want to do asynchronously - it just saves a user into my mongoDB database:

```
@Async
public Future<Void> saveUser(String userid) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(userid);
    return new AsyncResult<Void>(mongoTemplate.save(user));
}
```

The method gives me an errors as `mongoTemplate.save(user)` returns a `void` value and not a `Void` object.

I tried to change the method by substituting in `void` as follows but it does not work as `Future<void>` and `AsyncResult<void>` is not accepted:

```
@Async
public Future<void> saveUser(String userid) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(userid);
    return new AsyncResult<void>(mongoTemplate.save(user));
}
```

Is there anyway to run a method that returns void in an asynchronous way on Spring?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@Async
public void saveUser(String userid) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(userid);
    mongoTemplate.save(user);
}
```

Future needs to be used only when there is return type other than void.

Answer (score 10):

The only value a `Void` can have is `null`. So all you need is

```
User user = new User();
user.setUserId(userid);
mongoTemplate.save(user)
return new AsyncResult<Void>(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply return

```
return new AsyncResult<>(null);
```